# Move formula to various cells but only update one column reference

Tags: excel

I need help doing the following: This is my formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B5:B33;B53:B57);C53:C57)
```

I need to copy this formula to multiple cells in the same row (no gaps) and only the first column reference should be updated. So the formula should continue like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C5:C33;B53:B57);C53:C57)
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(D5:D33;B53:B57);C53:C57)
```

and so on.

How do I do this? The issue is that B53;B57 and C53;C57 are lookup values needed in the formula.

Will provide more info if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Use [Absolute References](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

Comment: And thats it... plain and simple. Thanks! :)